# product image thumbnail didn`t work on direction:rtl

Tags: magento2.3, attributes, product-images, frontend, design

I used magento 2.3.2 ,when i used

- {
  direction:rtl;
  }

on pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/ar_SA/css/styles-l.css

the product image thumbnail didn`t work

[image]

any one can help me to make it work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Changing default theme in RTL, Create theme http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html

Then add below CSS in less file

```
body {
  direction:rtl;
  unicode-bidi:embed
}
```

Comment: thanx alot it`s fixed ^_^